# How to wait for other functions answers in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am pretty new to typeScript, I am trying to make a simple JavaScript library using TypeScript.

I have an event listener which is for window `load` and when the window loaded I fill some of my config (which are variables) and I need to run other functions after the load callback and also those configs filler.

I used a library which is for `promise` but that was very heavy and also not famous on GitHub, when I added to the typeScript the bundled javascript file became over 15k! I just wrote some lines of code but the promise was complicated!

What should I do for promises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use typescript >= 2.1 (if you need to compile to ES5), >= 1.7 (for ES6 only) and `async/await`

```
try {

    const result = await funcThatReturnsAPromise()
    //do other stuff after the promise succeeded

} catch(e) {

   //do stuff when promise fails (rejects)
}
```

[Documentation for 1.7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/11/30/announcing-typescript-1-7/)

[Support for ES3/ES5 target in 2.1](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html)

Support for ES3/ES5 TL;DR;

- add a [Promise Polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)
- change compiler options in tsconfig.json

  ```
   "compilerOptions": {
       "lib": ["dom", "es2015.promise", "es5"]
   }
  ```

Comment: I need to compile it to es5 and then use browserfy to bundle all files, you mean, there is a default promise in typeScript?

Comment: can you please describe more? the document you sent is for version 1.7